# Custom django-admin templates

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates

I've got a model, and my instance called **"show_user_image"**:

```
class user_image(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  img = models.imageField(upload_to='/home/blabla')

  def show_user_image(self):
    return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.img.url
  show_user_image.short_description = 'User image'
  image_img.allow_tags = True
```

off course i can use it at my admin list:

```
list_display = ('title', 'show_user_image')
```

And my question is: how to use this instance in the edit form?

Something like here:
http://new-media.djangobook.com/content/en/1.0/chapter17/book_extra.png

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block form_top %}
  <p>Insert meaningful help message here...</p>
{% endblock %}
```

but i want:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block form_top %}
  {{ MY-INSTANCE-HERE }}
{% endblock %}
```

I just need to image display above the form.

Thanks!
John.

Comment: You don't show any instances. Do you mean method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is admin template is available via `adminform.form` variable. Your field is named `img`, so it will be like this (untested):

```
{% block form_top %}
   <img src="{{ adminform.form.img.value }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

BTW. Class names in python should use CapitalizedWordsNamingConvention, according to official [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You should name the model `UserImage` instead of `user_image`.

BTW2: `show_user_image` is a **method**, not an **instance**.